# cant play local sound

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player

**when i press the sound button it show error :**
E/flutter (30513): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/sound/1.mp3
E/flutter (30513): #0 PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:237
E/flutter (30513):
E/flutter (30513): #1 AudioCache.fetchToMemory
package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:89
E/flutter (30513):
E/flutter (30513): #2 AudioCache.load
package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:115
E/flutter (30513):
E/flutter (30513): #3 AudioCache.play
package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:159
E/flutter (30513):
E/flutter (30513):

**and i have been edited the pubspec.yaml already :**

flutter:

uses-material-design: true
assets:

- sound/

Comment: I'm using audioplayers by blue-fire.xyz

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the complete path, see this example below (each in its own line):

```yaml
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/sounds/
```